# header ('Location: ') in PHP not redirecting

Tags: php, header, location

**login.php**

```
<form class="form-signin" action="#" method="POST">
            <span id="reauth-email" class="reauth-email"></span>
            <input type="text" name="usern" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
            <input type="password" name="passw" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
            <div id="remember" class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
                </label>
            </div>
            <input onClick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" type="submit" name="sub" value="Login">
        </form>
```

**PHP script**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['sub']))
{
include('user.php');
$us = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['usern']);
$pw = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['passw']);

if(!empty($_POST['usern']) || !empty($_POST['passw']))
{
        $query = "SELECT ID FROM myuser WHERE username = '$us' AND
        password = SHA('$pw')";
            $result = @mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        if($row)
        { 
                header('Location: homepage.php');
                exit;
        }
            else  
            {
                echo '<script language="javascript">';
                echo 'alert("Invalid Username/Password")';
                echo '</script>';   
            }
}
        else
        {
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Please enter Username/Password")';
            echo '</script>';
            mysqli_close($conn);
        }
} 
?>
```

I can't make the header location work! I don't know why, I've already search some fixes and threads but nothing work out. How can I revise my code, can anyone spot the error?

Comment: Put your code directly in your question. Don't post screenshots of code.

Comment: Okay, I wouldn't do that next time. Sorry im new here hehe

Comment: There's an "edit" link under your question. You can click that to make modifications.

Comment: Please fix it _this_ time, thanks.

Comment: Note that SHA is not a safe hash algorithm for passwords - it can be brute-force searched too easily.

Comment: (While the code is contained in an image, this question needs to be put on hold, and it presently has 2/5 votes to get it there.)

Comment: @halfer I fixed my post now... sorry if it takes some time, I was still finding a fix for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just finally solved it guys! 
What I did was ditch mysqli and went using PDO.
Here's my new code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$h = "localhost";
$u = "root"; 
$p = "";
$db = "user";
$msg = "";

try
{
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$h; dbname=$db", $u, $p);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

        if(isset($_POST["sub"]))
        {
            if(empty($_POST["usern"]) || empty($_POST["passw"]))
            {
                $msg = "<label>Please enter username/password!</label>";
            }
            else
            {
                $sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM myuser WHERE username = :username AND password = :password";
                $stat = $con->prepare($sqlquery);
                $stat->execute(
                        array(
                            ':username' => $_POST["usern"],
                            ':password' => $_POST["passw"]
                        )
                );
                $countrow = $stat->rowCount();
                if($countrow > 0)
                {
                    $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["usern"];
                    header("Location: homepage.php");
                }
                else
                {
                    $msg = "<label>Invalid username/password</label>";
                }
            }
        }
}

catch(PDOException $er)
{
    $msg = $er->getMessage();
}   
?>
```

Comment: I also found another fix without changing to PDO just change your database password type to varchar(255) because sha will encrypt your password so for example your 123456789 password will be 60 to 100 characters. (255 was for future proofing) That's why my fetch array doesn't return true because my password doesn't matching with the sha encrypted password because I only have varchar(40) in my database password which is not recommended when you hash your password.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "http('s' if needed)://your_domain/homepage.php

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
if($row) {
```

to:

```
if(!empty($row)) {
```

Hope this works.

If the solution #1 doesn't work try to change:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

to:

```
$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

and:

```
if($row) {
```

to:

```
if($row > 0) {
```

;)

Comment: No luck! My mysqli_fetch_array doesn't return TRUE even if I changed it to mysqli_num_rows it's still the same.

Comment: It can't return a boolean value. It returns a array of rows in the table that you searched. The solution #1 returns a boolean by checking if the 'row array' is not empty. The solution #2 check if the number of rows in the searched table is more than 0.

Comment: I mean those two solution you provide didn't worked because the if else statement doesn't return true and I don't know why... Anyway, I just fixed it by using PDO.

Answer (score -1):

[mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) doesn't return **`true`**.

```
if($row !== false){
    header("Location: homepage.php");
}
```

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array` returns an array. If you do `if ($array)` and `$array` is non-empty, it will return `true`. See http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know. :) Anyway, there's still possible function returns false. Did you tried putting your header() in first line to test does this function works ar all?

Comment: I would delete this answer and put that comment under the question instead.

Comment: @mpz, Just to be clear. Does your user.php contains any echo? Ther can't be any data before header.

Comment: @NikitaCunskis there is no echo on user.php anyway, I tried the code above it's redirecting to homepage.php but now the else for "Invalid Username/Password" doesn't work! I'll try tinkering this code... I will let you know if it works.

Comment: @Mike I need 50 reputation to write comments.

Comment: @NikitaCunskis You realize you said that with a comment, right? You can always comment on your own posts, and any part of your questions. However, commenting on other people's posts is a privilege gained from earning reputation.

Answer (score -1):

PHP 5.6 and higher doesn't support redirect with headers.
For solve this issue use redirecting with JavaScript like below code

```
if($row){
     echo '<script>window.location = "YOUR_URL";</script>';
}
```

Comment: This isn't remotely true - all versions of PHP support HTTP header output, including `Location` redirects. Can you expand on why you think it does not?

Comment: yes support but location need separate module in this versions and some of shared hostings disable this module

Comment: I've not heard of that, Salar. I'm [reading the manual](http://php.net/header) and as far as I can tell, `header()` is a core function. It does say _Headers will only be accessible and output when a SAPI that supports them is in use_ - what configuration have you found does not send headers to the client? Do you have IIS/Windows in mind? Shared PHP hosting nearly always runs on Linux, as far as I know.

Comment: Dude its not my problem I just answered for solve problem and my code works fine :)

Comment: JavaScript is a solution that can break far more easily than HTTP redirects.